# Simplest possible working cometd java client

Tags: java, cometd

I've been trying to get a very simple cometd java server and client setup, using cometd version 3.1.2 and jetty 9.4.6.v20170531, using the code from cometd's documentation.

```
HttpClient httpClient = new HttpClient();
httpClient.start();

Map<String, Object> options = new HashMap<String, Object>();
ClientTransport transport = new LongPollingTransport(options, httpClient);
BayeuxClient client = new BayeuxClient("http://localhost:9025/mycontext/cometd/", transport);

client.handshake();
boolean handshaken = client.waitFor(5000, BayeuxClient.State.CONNECTED);
if (handshaken) {
  System.out.println("Yes");
  // Here handshake is successful
}
System.out.println("Done");
```

The server setup is what I'm really interested in, and is a spring injected embedded jetty server with the cometd servlet. No matter what I've tried the client will not handshake. I was finally able to prove that the server is correctly setup and available by send this request via postman...

POST http://localhost:9025/mycontext/cometd

```
[{
    "version": "1.0",
    "minimumVersion": "0.9",
    "channel": "/meta/handshake",
    "supportedConnectionTypes": [
        "long-polling", 
        "callback-polling"
    ],
    "advice": {
        "timeout": 60000,
        "interval": 0
    },
    "id": "1"
}]
```

...which returns a 200...

```
[
    {
        "minimumVersion": "1.0",
        "clientId": "11jlmrekgqnu9v1i4w1b8rgiq3c",
        "supportedConnectionTypes": [
            "long-polling",
            "websocket"
        ],
        "advice": {
            "interval": 0,
            "timeout": 60000,
            "reconnect": "retry"
        },
        "channel": "/meta/handshake",
        "id": "1",
        "version": "1.0",
        "successful": true
    }
]
```

...so, clearly, the server setup is fine. I've set break points and used tcpflow to look for traffic and from what I can tell, the simplest possible client using cometd's own libraries from their starter documentation never sends any request at all. No tcp traffic. Anyone know what I'm missing? Any help appreciated.

Comment: "No matter what I've tried the client will not handshake." Is there a specific error that it's throwing?

Answer (score 1):

You must have something else going on.

Your code is correct, and the CometD test suite uses exactly that code for hundreds of tests and it's working fine.

Please have a read at the [troubleshooting section](https://docs.cometd.org/current/reference/#_troubleshooting) of the [CometD documentation](https://docs.cometd.org/current/reference).

As a suggestion, enable DEBUG logging level for the `org.cometd` category, and look at the logs you obtain: it should be evident what the problem is.

Feel free to attach the logs to an issue at the [CometD Issue Tracker](https://github.com/cometd/cometd/issues) if you still have problems.